# How to: Set default values for required column in a SharePoint 2016 newform.aspx using javascript

Tags: javascript, newform

I have a simple list with a single line of text column. I have a JS function that reads data from other list an set default value for this column in the new form. I simply use.

$(“select[Title=’Fieldname’]”).val(‘Value’);

All works well, if I change my column type and set "Require that this column contains information" to true, the code no longer works. Anyone knows why and how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the the field required it changes the title attribute of field element . So the selector you are using does not return any element.

You can see the title of the field by inspecting respective textbox/select element on new form in developer tool.

Try using below selectors:

**Using Title property**:

```
$("select[title='Fieldname Required Field']").val("Value");
```

Here Fieldname is display name of field.

**Using Id property**:

Using Id for element selector is bit tricky in SharePoint as it appends unnecessary string in id attribute by default.

```
$("select[id^='Fieldname']").val("Value");
```

`^` denotes that id `starts with` your Fieldname (Internal name of field). You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much. I used $(“select[id=’Fieldid']”).val(‘Value’); so I dont have to worry about updating the title

Comment: Yes, but using Id for element selector is bit tricky in SharePoint. see updated answer.

Comment: @samSahelly If this answer helped you in any way then please accept an answer so that other users can get help from accepeted answer easily.